# Novel about a female detective investigating a crime in a society where mind reading through brain scanning is done

Tags: story-identification, novel, detective

I remember lines in the book describing the dark neural paths of the criminal being investigated and the female detective describing that she enjoyed the hunt through the twisting pathways and maybe something about the sudden changes in memories from light to darkness of thought, ( although that might be my own thoughts visualizing the story ).

Very much appreciated if anyone could suggest titles to look up.

Comment: Hi. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: I remember buying this book in the '90s. I used to live in Melbourne at the time and frequented a well known SciFi/Fantasy store called Space Age bookshop opposite Royal Melbourne University of Technology.  Cover was a sort of baby-vomit yellow background with a darker image of twisted and curling labyrinth ( likely to signify the mind being investigated ). The author might be female, for some reason that's in the back of my mind, but not sure.

Answer (score 8):

Possibly [Queen of Angels](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen_of_Angels_(novel)) by Greg Bear:

> The central unifying element involves a famous writer, Emmanuel
> Goldsmith, who has committed a gruesome series of murders, a crime
> almost unheard of in the age of therapy. **One storyline involves Mary
> Choy, a high natural police detective assigned to the case to track
> down and arrest the murderer.** Mary is a transform since she has chosen
> to have her body extensively altered by nanotechnology to enhance her
> abilities as a policewoman and also for aesthetic reasons.

> The third plot line concerns Martin Burke, a
> pioneer in psychotherapy who uses a technique which allows him to
> **directly enter and interact with a patient's psychology, the "Country
> of the Mind," through a sort of virtual reality**. Although disgraced at
> the story's opening, **Dr. Burke is given the opportunity to use his
> technique to explore Goldsmith's mind, which turns out to be one of
> the most fascinating and dangerous minds imaginable.**

Comment: Wow ! That's genius. Thank you I will look that up.  The name Mary Choy rings a bell !